# Does Always Encrypted cause blocking queries or locking object?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I have perform some test with relatively small tables and the encryption took a very long time (maybe because there are many SQL objects that are referring the target table).

I am wondering(worrying) when a table is being encrypted, is it possible to read the encrypted data or query the table? I only found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-using-sql-server-management-studio#rotating-column-master-keys):

> While the data is being re-encrypted, your applications cannot write
>   to the impacted tables. Therefore, your organization needs to plan a
>   column encryption key rotation very carefully.

and it is about the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Column *encryption* key rotation will probably block since it is doing mass updates from a client across a network.  We learned to absolutely lock users out of the system while a column is being encrypted with a new CEK.